# Is there a way to create a scatter plot where a subset of a column is on the x-axis and a different subset is on the y-axis?

Tags: altair

I'm trying to create a compound chart to display a correlation matrix and a scatterplot showing the individual data points used to calculate each correlation coefficient. I would like to be able to filter the values encoded in `x` and `y` of the scatter plot based on a selection in the correlation matrix (e.g. clicking on the square corresponding to *condition a* vs *condition b* in the correlation matrix pulls up the scatter plot where each point is (*value in condition a*, *value in condition b*)).

The only way I've gotten this to work is by first generating a dataframe containing all the possible pairs of datapoints, and then using that in an Altair Chart.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id': ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
        'condition': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
        'value': np.arange(12)
    }
)

paired_df = pd.concat(
    pd.merge(
        df.loc[df.condition == condition_x],
        df.loc[df.condition == condition_y],
        on='id'
    )
    for condition_x in ['a', 'b', 'c'] for condition_y in ['a', 'b', 'c']
)

corr = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'condition_x': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'a', 4: 'b', 5: 'c', 6: 'a', 7: 'b', 8: 'c'},
        'condition_y': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'b', 4: 'b', 5: 'b', 6: 'c', 7: 'c', 8: 'c'},
        'r^2': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 1.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 1.0, 8: 1.0}
    }
)

selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['condition_x', 'condition_y'])

heatmap = alt.Chart(corr).mark_rect().encode(
    x='condition_x',
    y='condition_y',
    color='r^2',
).add_selection(selection)
heatmap

scatter = alt.Chart(paired_df).mark_circle().transform_filter(
    selection
).encode(
    x='value_x',
    y='value_y',
)

heatmap | scatter
```

However, the datasets that I am working with are too large to do this kind of pairwise transformation without a big performance cost. Is there a more idiomatic way to do this through Altair? I was hoping I could make a pivot table and choose the columns for the `x` and `y` encodings by accessing the values of `condition_x` and `condition_y` fields of the `selection`, but I haven't been able to find any examples of this. Maybe something like:

```
scatter = alt.Chart(paired_df).mark_circle().transform_pivot(
    'condition',
    groupby=['id'],
    value='value'
).encode(
    x=selection['condition_x'],
    y=selection['condition_y'],
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural way to do this might be with something like `transform_lookup`, but unfortunately that only provides left-join semantics, not cross-join semantics. But digging into Altair's available transforms, it seems like you can do what you want with a careful combination of a [pivot transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/pivot.html) and two [fold transforms](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/fold.html).

Here is the equivalent `scatter` chart built from `df` rather than `paired_df`:

```python
scatter = alt.Chart(df).transform_pivot(
    "condition", value="value", groupby=["id"]
).transform_fold(
    ["a", "b", "c"], as_=["condition_x", "value_x"]
).transform_fold(
    ["a", "b", "c"], as_=["condition_y", "value_y"]
).mark_circle().transform_filter(
    selection
).encode(
    x='value_x:Q',
    y='value_y:Q',
)
```